# PIC16F690 Consecutive flashing LED's

Tags: microcontroller, led, pic, assembly

I am having trouble writing the code for flashing 6 LED's from PORTC on the PIC16F690 microcontroller.  The LED's should flash like the lights on a runway.

With the code that I currently have the LED's are flashing in pairs and out of order.

Here is the code that I have currently:

```
list p=16F690
radix hex
include "P16F690.INC"
__config _WDT_OFF & _BOR_OFF & _PWRTE_ON & _INTOSCIO & _MCLRE_OFF
errorlevel -302
org 0

count equ 20        ;we're going to need two variables
count2 equ 21

call initial
call Blink

initial         ; initialize registers
    bsf STATUS, RP0
    movlw B'00000000'
    movwf TRISC
    bcf STATUS, RP0
    bsf STATUS, RP1
    clrf ANSEL
    clrf ANSELH
    bcf STATUS, RP1
    return

Blink            ;flip the LED on or off
    movlw B'00000001'
    rlf PORTC,F
    call Delay
    call Blink

Delay           ; waste time
    movlw 0xFF
    movwf count
    movwf count2
Delayloop
    decfsz count,f
    goto Delayloop
    decfsz count2,f
    goto Delayloop
    return

END
```

Comment: Please explain the exact behaviour you expect from the LEDs and the behaviour you are seeing now.

Comment: And what's that "movlw B'00000001'" doing right after Blink label?

Comment: Assuming all the rest is working you probably just need to move your (attempt of) initialization of PORTC right at the end of Initial sub.

Comment: At the moment the LED's are flashing in pairs through the pins in PORTC.  However I would like the LED's to flash one by one, starting from RC0 to RC7.

Answer (score 3):

There are some problems with your code. I will point them out in order of which I think they may be the actual problem here. The ones at the bottom are just best-practice tips.

---

## Initalise PORTC

You never initialise `PORTC`. The value of `PORTC` is *unknown* on a Power-On Reset. You will have to set it to some value in your `initial` routine:

```
movlw 0x01
movwf PORTC
```

This sets it to have one LED on, which is probably what you want. After that, with `RLF`, you will start rotating this bit to light other LEDs.

It may be that this is the idea behind these lines in `blink`:

```
movlw B'00000001'
rlf PORTC,F
```

However, the first line doesn't have any effect: it stores `0b00000001` in W, but W is never used. `RLF` takes register `PORTC`, rotates it and stores it back in `PORTC` - W isn't used. Also, you execute `movlw B'00000001'` every time you loop through `blink`.  Even if this would correct, than the value of `PORTC` would never change because its reset all the time: you have to initialise the port in the `initial` routine, and change it in the `blink` routine.

---

## Call and goto

```
Blink            ;flip the LED on or off
    movlw B'00000001'
    rlf PORTC,F
    call Delay
    call Blink
```

There are three different types of instructions to jump in code: `GOTO`, `CALL` and `RETURN`.

- With `GOTO`, you simply jump in the code - it's as easy as that.
- With `CALL`, you implement `GOTO` but also push the current program counter on the stack. This stack is a LIFO (last in first out) memory module in which in this case program locations can be stored.
- With `RETURN`, you pop the last element from the stack and jump to that location. Essentially you jump to the instruction after the last executed `CALL`. This is what you use in the beginning where you call to `Initial` and then return and call to `Blink`.

The stack of this chip has eight levels, as described in section 2.3.2 of [the datasheet](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/41262A.pdf). That means you can push a maximum of eight program locations on this stack. After that, the first index is overwritten (the stack is implemented as a circular buffer). This essentially means that it is then not possible to go back to the first `CALL` instruction, and that the controller will jump to another position. This may cause many unexplainable problems in more advanced software.

With the code I quoted above, you continuously call `Blink`, but there is no `RETURN` instruction. This means you will keep pushing stuff to the stack without popping it. The stack is being overwritten all the time. Since you don't use `RETURN` there, it doesn't matter so much. But in this situation you should really use `GOTO` instead of `CALL`:

```
Blink            ;flip the LED on or off
    movlw B'00000001'
    rlf PORTC,F
    call Delay
    goto Blink
```

Since `GOTO` doesn't use the stack, this is no problem.

---

## Org 0 and 4

You've put lots of stuff on `org 0`. This is not good practice. As can be read in section 2.1 of [the datasheet](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/41262A.pdf), this chip has an interrupt vector at `org 4`. This means that when an interrupt occurs, the program counter will jump to location 4, almost directly after 0. This is why we normally implement just a `GOTO` instruction on `org 0`. Something like this:

```
org 0
    goto start
org 4
    retfie            ; return from interrupt (alternatively you could have 
                      ; an interrupt handler here)

start: 
    ; your main code...
```

---

## Explicit radices

As I already mentioned in the comments: in the top of your program you stated `radix hex` (and this is also the default). Because of this you can use `EQU 20` to select register `0x20`. However, it's much clearer when you just use `EQU 0x20` or `EQU 20h`. When others read your code, they don't have to search for the radix specification or the assembler's default.

---

## Delay generator

Maybe you know already about this, but you may find this interesting: http://www.piclist.com/techref/piclist/codegen/delay.htm

This is a delay generator which will generate a delay of a specific time for you. Your delay routine is perfect as far as I can see now, but if you're ever looking for something that calculates it exactly, here you go!

Comment: Did it also help? :)

Comment: So far I am still trying to debug.  As of now, no LED's are lighting up.  But I do understand my code much better.

Comment: I will look in the morning then to see if I can spot something else.

Comment: Hey Camil great answer, about the "RLF rx,d" instruction he uses 'F' as 'd', while in the spec 'd' should either be 0 or 1. I'm guessing 'F' equals '1' in this case, but wouldn't be better to just put '1' there?

Comment: @VladimirCravero F indeed equals 1 in this cases, and instead of 0 one could use W. My opinion would be that F and W is more expressive and preferable (just as using BANKSEL instead of changing the RPx bits manually, and as using PORTA instead of 0x05) - but it's all opinions of course. Do you have a particular reason to prefer 1 over F?

Comment: I thought that F was the digit F, but it seems that F and W are special characters so F is better, no doubt.

Answer (score 2):

There is so much bad programming in your example that a proper answer would take too long.  There is absolute mode, manual bank setting, fixed placement of variables, hidden but implied assumptions about the bank setting, and overflowing of the call stack.  What a mess!  Maybe I have time to wade thru all that tomorrow.

However, the code at BLINK is particularly confused and likely the source of the trouble.  I can't even guess what you think loading 1 into W is supposed to accomplish.  The lack of comments is downright irresponsible.  In your description above the code, you talk of several LEDs, but the comment at BLINK talks only of flipping a single LED.  The real bug seems to be that RLF doesn't work as you seem to think, although without comments one can't tell what you are thinking.  Note that the rotate is performed on 9 bits, the register and the C bit.

This should be easy to debug.  Load this into MPLAB and run it in the simulator.  Then you can single step thru the program and see what every instruction is doing.